# UIView doesn't appear as expected

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

In the process of learning how to use UIView animation to create animated bar charts in my larger project, I've read a good bit in the Apple docs on UIViews, and also successfully gone through Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on animating views.

Now I've made a tiny little app to help me apply the process. I plan to expand the app to include animation, but for the moment the idea is that when I tap the "Go" button, a red square appears. BarView is a custom UIView class. Here's the relevant code:

```
- (IBAction)gobutton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Create a new BarView view
    CGRect  aBarFrame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 20);

    BarView *aBar = [[BarView alloc]initWithFrame:aBarFrame];
    aBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [aBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

However, nothing appears.

Can someone please point out my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: is the function getting called? put a break point inside.

Comment: Yes, it is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
[self.view addSubview:aBar];
```

Comment: Thanks, however do you understand *why* its the solution, so you can learn?

Comment: Yes, I believe I do. Thanks again!